# adding additional items to same key isolatedstoragesettings

Tags: windows-phone, isolatedstorage

like the title says, I want to add additional values to a isolatedstoragesetting.

my scenario is I am making a call to get a list of objects, which I save to isolatedstorage, then when I run the app again the another call is made, but it returns the latest new result, which I want to add to the previous isolatedstorage key.

how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

:D
The only way to do this would be to read the data in the key to a list, add your new items and then save over the key again.

Isolated storage is just a simple string/blob key value pair storage, it has no understanding of what is stored there hence why you need to cast the data to an appropriate type when reading / deserialising it.

Hope this helps